How many ballistic missiles does the PRC have 'pointed' at Taiwan, according to Western estimates?
In his essay why Ukraine can't win JD Vance argued (among other things) that

in March alone, Russia reportedly launched over 3,000 guided aerial bombs, 600 drones and 400 missiles at Ukraine. [...]  To fend off these attacks, the Ukrainian president, Volodymyr Zelensky, and others have indicated they need thousands of Patriot interceptors per year. The problem is this: The United States only manufactures 550 per year. If we pass the supplemental aid package currently being considered in Congress, we could potentially increase annual production to 650, but that’s still less than a third of what Ukraine requires.
These weapons are not only needed by Ukraine. If China were to set its sights on Taiwan, the Patriot missile system would be critical to its defense.

How many ballistic missiles does the PRC have 'pointed' at Taiwan though? If the PRC does go "all out" on bombing Taiwan with ballistic missiles, would even sending the whole US Patriots' production be enough though, to prevent most critical infrastructure in Taiwan from looking like a Ukrainian front-line town today (or like an increasing proportion of its power plants)? Are there any estimates on PLA's ability to bomb Taiwan from afar, should they choose that course of action, including in a prolonged (years long) campaign? Does e.g. China have or can make much fewer missiles with a range that can reach Taiwan (compared to Russia's similar-ranged arsenal, which they're using against Ukraine)?
For the sake of making this relevant (vis-a-vis of the quote) and answerable, I'm looking for Western estimates, as it's these that Western politicians will be using when making their assessments. E.g. I was able to find out that Taiwan's legislature gets briefed on such matters:

The number of ballistic and cruise missiles aimed by China’s Second Artillery Corps at Taiwan has grown from 1,400 last year to more than 1,600 this year, which poses a serious threat to the nation, the Ministry of National Defense (MND) said in its China Military Power Report 2012. This year’s annual report, which has been delivered to the legislature, emphasizes China’s growing missile threat.

But that (quote) combines ballistic and cruise missiles (which need different counters), and it's also pretty dated.

Most of these -3,000 guided aerial bombs, 600 drones  - would not be anywhere near Patriot-relevant.  Having read Hillbilly years ago, not impressed with its author here.  Nor your citation here.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: well, I'm a bit skeptical of the reasoning, hence the Q. It's been questioned on a diplomatic level as well, but that's a bit besides the point, as Vance is making it all a [military] numbers game.

I guess this information and related ones like the real US Patriot production is a military secret and cannot be answered with information available to the public. I therefore don't think that this question is answerable with any reasonable uncertainty. It's also not directly about politics.

I’m voting to close this question because it cannot be answered with public information with any reasonable uncertainty because it's asking for a military secret.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Patriot production is hardly that secret.  Lockheed Martin has said it is increasing its U.S. output of Patriot interceptors from 500 to 650 by 2027  In the West, purchases will be on the budget and the manufacturers will also communicate to their shareholders.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica But Patriot isn't the only anti-ballistic missile system. Maybe there are other, cheaper systems. Ukraine manages to catch quite a large number of Russian missiles, which are guided, not ballistic, so different but nevertheless.

A probable undercount from 2021 gives an order of magnitude idea:
2021
Understanding the People’s Liberation Army Rocket Force

Every year between 2002 and 2009, the PRC deployed approximately fifty to one hundred new ballistic missiles opposite Taiwan, with the number of missiles currently arrayed against Taiwan equaling at least one thousand.

In the larger scheme of things, Ukraine is not near as encouraging to China as it might seem.  Yes, China is bigger than Russia, but invading across a wide stretch of water is a big logistical challenge.  Nor does the PRC have near the level of actual combat experience as Russia.  But most importantly, it shows to the Taiwanese that resisting is not a foregone conclusion to an immediate loss.
Last, Taiwan is not Ukraine.  Ukraine is a strategic, if not moral, sideshow for the West.  Losing it, as was widely anticipated in February 2022, would not change US security very much overall.  Taiwan's extreme dominance of sub-5nm computer chips gives it a position more analogous to Saudi Arabia's petroleum relevance 20 years ago.  That Trump is too dense to understand that doesn't change that fact.

Former US President Donald Trump has said Taiwan should pay the US to protect it from China and accused the country of taking “all [its] chip business.”


The comments from Trump were made in an interview with Bloomberg Businessweek on July 16.


Asked if he would defend Taiwan against China if he is re-elected in November, Trump said that the country – which the US does not formally recognize – should pay the US for protection.

Taiwanese politicians are very much engaged with a tug of war internally wrt China.  China hopes to badger them into reunification and parties like the KMT are angling on that side.
What if the Taiwanese electorate takes Trump at his word, loses hope and says:  "You know what?  China is too powerful and Trump's USA won't lift a hand.  Let's reunify without a fight."
What then oh very stable genius?  What does the US do?  How does it ensure supply of advanced chips from a country that is under the yoke of its Trump-designated enemy?  It's like Reagan's USA saying "let's not help Saudi against Iran unless they pay us".
Thankfully there is always the treatment of Hong Kong to focus Taiwanese minds on the consequences of reunification.

Wow, China seems to be really lagging if they only make <100/year. Russia makes like 35/month according to Ukrainian estimates -- just counting the Iskander-M and Kinzhal. And around 80 cruise missiles/month, of various types, although Patriots aren't a good fit/defence against the latter.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever Russia seems to have massively ramped up the production of some of its cheaper, more effective, gear since 2022.  That counts for missiles and artillery shells, less so for artillery barrels.  At a guess, there is a lot more money going in and somewhat less getting siphoned off by corruption (bad form in wartime).  And the FAB gliding bombs are actually a clever hack to repurpose their massive stock of old dumb bombs.

This says they've increased production of Iskaner-M from 7/month to 30 in 2023, so not just cheap stuff. I guess China is still operating at their peacetime levels.

Count it under the "more effective" basket, rather than cheaper then.  Funny how little SU-57, T-14 Armata and other wunderwaffens they've bothered dealing with.  They fielded those dumb Terminator urban combat AFVs and that was a dud IIRC.  Ukraine would have been in a lot better place if the Reps had not had their hissy fit wrt assistance for 6+ months.  Again, chalk it under what a very stable genius with bone spurs contributes to US security.

I found the DoD's 2023 assessment of China's forces. They do assess separate forces in the "Taiwan straits area" but not for missiles. For those the DoD just gives figures for all China (p. 186):

Interestingly the number of MRBM/SRBM missiles fairly close to the one from the other answer, which if correct means China deploys about half its missiles of this kind around Taiwan.
